# C++: request for member is ambiguous

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class c1{
        public:
                void f(){std::cout<<"In f1\n";}
};
class c2{
        public:
                void f(){std::cout<<"In f2\n";}
};

template <typename T>
class c:public c1, c2 {
    T* pT;
public:
    T* operator->() { return pT; }
};

int main()
{
c<c1>* cMain;
cMain->f();
return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
g++ cache.cc
cache.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
cache.cc:22:8: error: request for member ‘f’ is ambiguous
 cMain->f();
        ^
cache.cc:9:8: note: candidates are: void c2::f()
   void f(){std::cout<<"In f2\n";}
        ^
cache.cc:5:8: note:                 void c1::f()
   void f(){std::cout<<"In f1\n";}
```

why is it not accessing the function f of c1 as specified in the template? is my template usage wrong? How can i make it point to the required class using template.?

Comment: Is `cMain` supposed to be a pointer?

Comment: What you probably meant to say was `(*cMain)->f()`, but that's still UB because `cMain` is uninitialized.

Comment: Shouldn't the template do `T* operator->() { return static_cast<T*>(this); }
`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using pointers. You aren't calling `c::operator->` but just dereferencing `cMain` which is uninitialized and leads to UB. Removing the pointers (for the most part) fixes the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

class c1{
public:
    void f(){std::cout<<"In f1\n";}
};
class c2{
public:
    void f(){std::cout<<"In f2\n";}
};

template <typename T>
class c { // No longer derives from c1 and c2
    T t; // No longer a pointer
public:
    T* operator->() { return &t; }
};

int main()
{
    c<c1> cMain; // No longer a pointer
    cMain->f(); // Calls c::operator->() now
    return 0;
}
```

[see it work](https://ideone.com/mnN5De)

Of course you don't need `c` to derive from `c1` and `c2` (or anything) for this to work.

Comment: Lets say c1 has function f1 and c2 has function f2 how can i map a function in c 'f' to both f1 and f2.

Comment: What do you mean by both? Do you want `c.f()` to call both functions? You can do something like in Bo Persson's answer.

Comment: the above i asked as a separate question here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854027/refer-to-function-of-different-base-class-according-to-template-parameter

Answer (score 2):

If you don't particularly need the pointer semantics for something else, you can add a function to `c` that redirects to the proper base class function:

```
template <typename T>
class c:public c1, c2 {
public:
   void f() { T::f(); }
};
```

Comment: Or even `using T::f;`

Comment: @Jarod42 - Right, I learned the redirection trick before there was a `using`. Hard to relearn the new language.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your calling code is equivalent to

```
c<c1>* cMain;
(*cMain).f(); // equivalent to: c<c1> cMain; cMain.f();
```

Value `*cMain` has type of `c<c1>`. Obviously, now a call to `f()` is ambiguous, because both `c1` and `c2` has `f()` function and `c<c1>` inherits them both. Templates are not to blame (you can make `class c` non-template and get the same result).

If you want to call `->` operator you should say `(*cMain)->f();` but don't forget to initialize the pointer before.