# Refer to function of different base class according to template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class c1 {
public:
    void f1() { std::cout << "In f1\n"; }
};

class c2 {
public:
    void f2() { std::cout << "In f2\n"; }
};

template<typename T>
class C: public c1, c2 {
public:
    void f() {

    };
};

int main() {
    C<c2> c;
    c.f();

    return 0;
}
```

is there any way based on `T` the function `f` in `C` can be mapped to function `f1` in `c1` and `f2` in `c2`? I am not clear how function `f` that can be used as a wrapper around `f1` and `f2` when i am pointing to a specific class using `T`

Note: I cannot modify class `c1` and `c2`. its out of my scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) from C++17. e.g.

```
void f() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, c1>)
        f1();
    else
        f2();
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/puvWlhTr1YIgbbsq)

Note that *constexpr if* is evaluated at compile-time, as @skypjack commented, for this case, it's pretty fine to be evaluated at run-time too. So the following code works fine too:

```
void f() {
    if (std::is_same_v<T, c1>)
        f1();
    else
        f2();
}
```

Comment: Nice. I always forget it's an option.

Comment: @StoryTeller It's such a convenient feature.

Comment: Very much so. Keeping the code in one place instead of scattering it is by far the best part.

Comment: Actually in this case [it just works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcdea6ead9d4f9db) even if you don't have `if constexpr` at your disposal. Maybe it's worth mentioning it. I wouldn't add another answer for that for it's really close to this one.

Comment: @skypjack - Yeah, but it isn't nearly as cool as when you have `if constexpr` :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Absolutely, but it works and C++17 isn't the first choice of each user here on so yet. Unfortunately, of course, for it has a lot of cool things actually!! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write a template like that. In several ways in fact. If you want to keep `C` as it is, then it's a simple matter of adding a type trait which contains a *pointer to a member function*

<kbd>[Live Example](https://ideone.com/yzPM5K)</kbd>

```
template<typename> struct which_member;

template<> struct which_member<c1> {
    static constexpr void (c1::* func)() = &c1::f1; 
};

template<> struct which_member<c2> {
    static constexpr void (c2::* func)() = &c2::f2; 
};

void f() {
    (static_cast<T*>(this)->*which_member<T>::func)();
}
```

The key is here `(static_cast<T*>(this)->*which_member<T>::func)();`. We cast `this` to the appropriate type pointer, then use the trait to retrieve the pointer to a member. And finally  we use the access operator `->*` on these two operands to obtain a callable expression. Which we then call (the outer `()`).

The cast isn't strictly needed, but I think the error message is more descriptive of the problem if you pass something that isn't a base class of `C` as the type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can specialise template:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class c1{
        public:
                void f1(){std::cout<<"In f1\n";}
};
class c2{
        public:
                void f2(){std::cout<<"In f2\n";}
};

template <typename T>
class C:public c1, c2 {
        public:
                void f()
                {
                };
};

template<> class C<c1>:public c1, c2 {
        public:
                void f()
                {
                  c1::f1();
                };
};

template<> class C<c2>:public c1, c2 {
        public:
                void f()
                {
                  c2::f2();
                };
};

int main()
{
        C<c2> c;
        c.f();
        return 0;
}
```